# Spring JUnit4 Test Hangs after few runs

Tags: spring, integration-testing, junit4, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring with DbUnit to test my DAOs. I have an TestExecutionListener to add/delete data from DB before and after each test class. Here is my abstract test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:spring/test-dao.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(
{ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,CleanInsertTestExecutionListener.class}
)
@DataSetLocation("classpath:data/test-dao-dataset.xml")
public abstract class AbstractDaoTests {
```

I have grouped my tests into a Suite and when I execute the Suite, only the first few tests run and then tests hangs indefinitely. Not sure what would be the cause of it. I don't see any exceptions either.
Any idea or pointers on what could be causing it would be very helpful.
I am able to run the individual tests but the issue happens when I try to run them in a suite.
Also, I am using Apache Commons pool BasicDataSource to access the DB.

Thanks,
Javid

Comment: Strange. The issue was with the Apache Commons DBCP. For some strange reason, the connection was blocking. I would assume it ran out of connections after few tests, but still can't understand why it would run out of connections.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
I was not closing the DBUnit Connection object in my TestExecutionListeners in the beforeTestClass & afterTestClass methods.
Closing the connection fixed the issue.

Thanks,
Javid